# SQLite query planner not using the best (covering) index

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, optimization, indexing

It seems like SQLite isn't choosing the right index for a query.

---

This is the current database I'm working on (in bold **the only relevant parts**):

CREATE TABLE match (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
competition CHAR );

**CREATE TABLE match_sit (
sit_number INTEGER,
match INTEGER,
type CHAR,
FOREIGN KEY(match) REFERENCES match(id) );**

CREATE INDEX match_comp ON match(competition);

**CREATE INDEX sit_match ON match_sit(match);**

**CREATE INDEX sit_type ON match_sit(type);**

**CREATE INDEX sit_match_type ON match_sit(match, type);**

---

If I run this query:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match_sit WHERE match<30000 AND type="g";

the run time is about 5 seconds.

The QUERY PLAN is:

SEARCH TABLE match_sit USING INDEX sit_type (type=?)

---

If i then drop the sit_type index and re-run the same query, the run time is about 0.5 seconds.

The QUERY PLAN becomes:

SEARCH TABLE match_sit USING COVERING INDEX sit_match_type (match<?)

---

So, *deleting* an index greatly improves the run time, because sqlite doesn't choose the best (covering) index until I delete the "wrong" one.

Why is this happening?

[here is an image about the whole situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHrPW.png)

Comment: Run `ANALYZE` after re-creating the index and see if the behavior changes?

Comment: And adding an index on `(type, match)` is probably going to work out to be a better option for this query than `(match, type)`.

Comment: Thanks, running ANALYZE solved the problem (and took quite a while). And yes, the index you suggested is preferred by the query planner over (match, type), could you explain why?

Comment: Give https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html and https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html a good read.

Comment: Will do, thank you again